# Convert Java code to NodeJS - Encryption method

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, cryptography, base64

I want to duplicate the JAVA encryption code in NodeJS.

```
private String DEFAULT_KEY = "abcdwAYserXbzcSeqL/zPg==";
private String text = "abc";
Base64 base64decoder = new Base64();
byte[] raw = base64decoder.decode(key);

SecretKeySpec fSecretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, fSecretKeySpec);
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());

Base64 base64encoder = new Base64();
result = base64encoder.encodeToString(encrypted);
System.out.println("result: "+ result);
```

The above code generate the encrypted code as: `ZkojvMTW+9EEK0owxMuA7A==`

I have tried few ways in NodeJS. It is not generating same code for me.

I have tried the following code.

```
var bKey = new Buffer('abcdwAYserXbzcSeqL/zPg==', 'base64');
var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-128-ecb',bKey);
//cipher.setAutoPadding(auto_padding=false);
var crypted = cipher.update('abc',null,'base64');
crypted+=cipher.final('base64');
console.log(crypted);
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: What have you tried?  Stackoverflow is a community that will help but you most show some code or things you have tried.

Comment: @JeffSloyer - This is the one way I have tried.

var bKey = new Buffer('abcdwAYserXbzcSeqL/zPg==', 'base64');

var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-128-ecb',bKey);
var encrypted = cipher.update('xls', 'base64', 'base64') + cipher.final('base64')

Comment: I added your code to your question.

Comment: What version of AES are you doing?

Comment: @JeffSloyer Thanks. I have tried with AES 128 bit used in java. So I used 'aes-128-ecb' first in nodejs code.Then I have tried  with all available ciphers in the NodeJS through the following code

'var chipers = crypto.getCiphers();

for (var i = 0; i < chipers.length; i++) {
 //Encryption method
}'

None of the ciphers gave the same result as JAVA. Please help me to identify the issue in NodeJS code.

Comment: Why are you base64 encoding the result and decoding the key?

Comment: I have to implement exactly same algorithm as in JAVA code(Business decision)

In java code they first decode the key and finally encoding the result. So I followed the same

Answer (score 1):

You probably are running into the issue that `createCipher` with two arguments takes a password, not a key. This password is first run through a key derivation function before it becomes a key.

Try to use the [`createCipheriv`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipheriv_algorithm_key_iv) method instead, using any value for the IV. ECB mode doesn't take an IV, but at least you would be using a key instead of a password.